# I am getting an error that says: "Umbrella header 'FaveButton-umbrella.h' not found", how do I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

I accidentally moved some files on my computer and now am getting the following error message:

> **Umbrella header 'FaveButton-umbrella.h' not found**

The error message was displayed to the right of line two in the following code:

```
framework module FaveButton {
  umbrella header "FaveButton-umbrella.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for the h. file that is associated to your project and put it back in the folder where the rest of your .h/.m files live. Try also a scan of the file name on `spotlight search` to retrieve the file.